# What's wrong with sorting this multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So I have to display this array using Java GUI, it's for a basketball season. We have team name, wins, losses and status. There are 10 teams 
I sort base on wins, descending order.I used bubble sort. The problem is when I tested the program, sometimes it only displayed 9 team names. 1 was missing and I don't know why, the wins,losses and statuses still displayed.
Here is the code:

```
int a,b,t;
String hTeam;
for(a=1;a<ConferenceSize;a++)
    for (b=ConferenceSize-1; b>=a;b--){
        if (Conference[b-1].wins<Conference[b].wins){

            t=Conference[b-1].wins;
            Conference[b-1].wins=Conference[b].wins;
            Conference[b].wins=t;


            hTeam = Conference[b-1].team;
            Conference[b -1].team=Conference[b].team;
            Conference[b].team=hTeam;

        }

    }

//OUTPUT
Team1name.setText(Conference[0].team);
Team2name.setText(Conference[1].team);
Team3name.setText(Conference[2].team);
Team4name.setText(Conference[3].team);
Team5name.setText(Conference[4].team);
Team6name.setText(Conference[5].team);
Team7name.setText(Conference[6].team);
Team8name.setText(Conference[7].team);
Team9name.setText(Conference[8].team);
Team10name.setText(Conference[9].team);

Team1win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[0].wins));
Team2win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[1].wins));
Team3win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[2].wins));
Team4win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[3].wins));
Team5win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[4].wins));
Team6win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[5].wins));
Team7win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[6].wins));
Team8win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[7].wins));
Team9win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[8].wins));
Team10win.setText(String.valueOf(Conference[9].wins));
```

Comment: what code displays it?

Comment: The convention is to make variables in lowercase, e.g. `conferenceSize` instead of `ConferenceSize`.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to output?

Comment: Are you using 1 based index or 0 based index in your array? if you're using zero based index, then change for(a=1;a<ConferenceSize;a++) to for(a=0;a<ConferenceSize;a++)

Comment: @sathya_dev Changing to `for(a=0...)` won't work without also changing the inner loop.

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/h4o4oau1h/

Comment: @Darynn Can you provide a test list of **"wins"** which causes this error and one which does not?